# Delete rows containing specific words with additional conditions in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I would like to get rid of rows where the word "plan" is included in keyword unless "advertising" or "marketing" is also included. Specifically in the sample dataset, the rows with keyword containing "hr plan" and "operation plan" should be deleted.

```
keyword <- c("advertising plan",
               "advertising budget",
               "marketing plan",
               "marketing budget",
               "hr plan",
               "hr budget",
               "operation plan",
               "operation budget")
indicator <- c(1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1)
sample <- cbind(keyword,indicator)
```

Comment: You may have missed something from the indicator vector, it's not the same length

Comment: Thanks for reminding

Answer (score 2):

Without using fancy regular expressions, I'd probably just go for combining your two rules:

```
sample[!(grepl("plan", sample[,"keyword"]) &
        (!grepl("marketing|advertising", sample[,"keyword"]))),]
#     keyword              indicator
#[1,] "advertising plan"   "1"      
#[2,] "advertising budget" "0"      
#[3,] "marketing plan"     "0"      
#[4,] "marketing budget"   "1"      
#[5,] "hr budget"          "1"      
#[6,] "operation budget"   "1"
```

Comment: It works well. Thanks for editing and answering my question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution using regex and the `stringr` package. As mentioned in the comments, i expanded the `indicator` for 2 more values. Basically you want to detect with the regular expression which `keyword`'s don't have "plan" in them or start with either "advertising" or "marketing". hth

```
library("tidyverse")
library("stringr")

keyword <- c("advertising plan",
             "advertising budget",
             "marketing plan",
             "marketing budget",
             "hr plan",
             "hr budget",
             "operation plan",
             "operation budget")

indicator <- c(1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1)

df <- data_frame(keyword,indicator)

    df %>% 
  filter(!keyword %>% stringr::str_detect("plan") | 
           keyword %>% stringr::str_detect(pattern = c("^advertising|marketing")))

# A tibble: 6 × 2
             keyword indicator
               <chr>     <dbl>
1   advertising plan         1
2 advertising budget         0
3     marketing plan         1
4   marketing budget         0
5          hr budget         1
6   operation budget         1
```

Comment: Your pattern search doesn't look for `plan` at all.

Comment: sorry - i understood that you want to get rid of all rows that contain "plan" _unless_ it starts with "advertising" or "marketing" - which is what this does

Comment: That looks better - although you can drop the `stringr::` prefixes I think - you've already loaded the `stringr` package so it should be okay.

Comment: sorry i kinda misunderstood the first time, now should be okay. yes you are right about the packges but thought better to be explicit in case somebody wonders.