# Create a column and assign values based on string variable in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe, data-manipulation

This is the sample data frame:

```
 keyword <- c("advertising plan","advertising budget",
         "marketing plan",
         "marketing budget",
         "hr plan",
         "hr budget",
         "operation plan",
         "operation budget")
 indicator <- c(1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1)
 df <- data_frame(keyword,indicator)
```

I need to create a new column called "Type", and assign "Type A" to the cells if the keyword contains "advertising" or "marketing" while assign "Type B" to the cells if the keyword contains "hr" or "operation".

Comment: Perhaps you could start by showing us some of the knowledge you have acquired after people kindly helped you in [your previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41623805/delete-rows-containing-specific-words-with-additional-conditions-in-r)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df$Type = ifelse(grepl("(advertising|marketing)",df$keyword),"Type A",0)
df$Type = ifelse(grepl("(hr|operation)",df$keyword),"Type B",df$Type)

> df
             keyword indicator   Type
1   advertising plan         1 Type A
2 advertising budget         0 Type A
3     marketing plan         1 Type A
4   marketing budget         0 Type A
5            hr plan         0 Type B
6          hr budget         1 Type B
7     operation plan         1 Type B
8   operation budget         1 Type B
```